# How to override CSS class with Styled-Components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to override `ant-tooltip-inner` css class using [Styled-Components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced).

Using normal `import './Tooltip.css'` everything works as intended.

```js
// import './Tooltip.css';            // Overrides
const StyledLayout = styled.div` 

  // Doesn't Work     
  &.ant-tooltip-inner {
    background-color: palevioletred !important;
    color: white !important;
  }

  // Works on other CSS class
  // default is light-blue - check Sidebar menu item in sandbox 
  .ant-menu:not(.ant-menu-horizontal) .ant-menu-item-selected {
    background-color: purple;
  }
`;

function CoolTooltip() {
  return (
    <StyledLayout>
      ...
    </StyledLayout>
  );
}
```

My goal is to **override all tooltips coloring** in my project (`ant-tooltip-inner`).

In this sandbox, all tooltips (of the `Sidebar` and `Tooltip`) need to be styled, uncommenting `import "./tooltip.css";` will work.

[image: Edit Override CssClass]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tooltips, Modal or similar components are rendered outside your SPA to improve the render performance of component tree.

Screenshot for same. [image]

In your case you're trying to style a single instance of a component which will NOT work via local styling. You may refer to antd docs to do so or you may override it globally ( css file or any other way as docs say).

Answer (score 0):

I already trying to override css of Modal from antd using styled-components, but still doesn't work as Kushalvm said above. I can override using pure CSS with className property from Modal.

See property API of antd Modal here --> https://ant.design/components/modal/